# Обход элементов вектора векторов

Tags: c++, циклы, vector

Я имею такую структуру данных, имитирующих матрицу значений:`vector <vector<int>> G`. Мне нужно написать функцию, которая принимает на вход такой вектор и возвращает такую же структуру данных, однако с измененными значениями.

```
vector<vector<int>> double_values(vector <vector<int>> G){
    for (int i = 0; i < G.size(), i++)
    {
        //здесь я могу итерироваться по строкам

        for (int j = 0; j < G[i].size; j++) {
             //но так я уже делать не могу
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне получить доступ к конкретным элементам внутренних векторов, если я не могу обращаться к ним как к `G[i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исправить ошибки - запросто можете:

```
for (int i = 0; i < G.size(); i++)
{
    //здесь я могу итерироваться по строкам

    for (int j = 0; j < G[i].size(); j++) {
        //но так я делать МОГУ
        cout << G[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Сами обнаружите, что я изменил? :)

И еще - незачем делать копию такого тяжеловесного объекта, как вектор векторов - передавайте его как константную ссылку.

А еще можно выполнять итерации с помощью цикла по диапазону:

```
for(const auto& F : G)
{
    for (auto k: F) {
        cout << k << endl;
    }
}
```